# Naming textarea don't create instance in form in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have this jade template for modal dialog using angular material (couldn't convert to html because the [jade site](http://jade-lang.com/demo/) is not working):

```
md-dialog(aria-label='Reject', ng-cloak='')
  form(name="rejectionForm")
    md-dialog-content
      .md-dialog-content
        h2.md-title Reject confirmation for
        div(ng-bind-html="vm.parent.task.label")
        div {{rejectionForm | json}}
        textarea(placeholder="Please provide a reason for rejection", name="reason", style="width: 530px; height: 75px", ng-required="true")
        div(ng-messages="rejectionForm.reason.$error")
          div(ng-message="required") You need to give the reason
    md-dialog-actions(layout="row")
      span(flex)
      md-button(ng-click="vm.parent.cancel()") CANCEL
      md-button.md-primary.md-raised(ng-click="vm.parent.reject()", ng-disabled="rejectionForm.$invalid") REJECT
```

it should create instance of form field in `rejectionForm` called `reason` but the resulting json look like this:

```
{
   "$error": {},
   "$name": "rejectionForm",
   "$dirty": false,
   "$pristine": true,
   "$valid": true,
   "$invalid": false,
   "$submitted": false
```

}

why there is no `reason` and why is my form not validated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have `ng-model` over `input` element with `name` attribute of form, it wouldn't add that `name` property in `rejectionForm` form object.

You should put `ng-model="something"` to get `reason` get populated inside `rejectionForm` form.